# when ever i am running multiple classes by using data provider getting [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

i am using java with selenium when ever i am running single class its running fine , but when i am using same data provider i am getting error mention below

## [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run

Usage:  [options] The XML suite files to run
Options:
-alwaysrunlisteners
Should MethodInvocation Listeners be run even for skipped methods
Default: true
-configfailurepolicy
Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
-d
Output directory
-dataproviderthreadcount
Number of threads to use when running data providers
-dependencyinjectorfactory
The dependency injector factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-excludegroups
Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
-failwheneverythingskipped
Should TestNG fail execution if all tests were skipped and nothing was
run.
Default: false
-groups
Comma-separated list of group names to be run
-junit
JUnit mode
Default: false
-listener
List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener
or ISuiteListener
-methods
Comma separated of test methods
Default: []
-methodselectors
List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
-mixed
Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with
appropriate runner
Default: false
-objectfactory
List of .class files or list of class names implementing
ITestRunnerFactory
-overrideincludedmethods
Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be
skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
Default: false
-parallel
Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none]
-port
The port
-reporter
Extended configuration for custom report listener
-spilistenerstoskip
Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be
skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
Default: 
-suitename
Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or
source code
-suitethreadpoolsize
Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
Default: 1
-testclass
The list of test classes
-testjar
A jar file containing the tests
-testname
Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source
code
-testnames
The list of test names to run
-testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
The factory used to create tests
-threadcount
Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
-threadpoolfactoryclass
The threadpool executor factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-usedefaultlisteners
Whether to use the default listeners
Default: true
-log, -verbose
Level of verbosity
-xmlpathinjar
The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if
-testjar was specified)
Default: testng.xml

please help me on this